# why does c# JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize return empty square brackets

Tags: c#, json, javascriptserializer

Why does the following code return "[ ]" when it should return "{"id":1999, "title":"hithere"}

```
    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    StringBuilder sbJsonResults = new StringBuilder();
    var result = serializer.Serialize(new dg(1999, "hithere"));

    context.Response.Clear();
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    context.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.MinValue);
    context.Response.Write(result);
```

P.S. the dg class looks like this:

```
    public class dg : ScheduleObserver, ILibrary, IEnumerable {
        public int id;
        public string title;
        private List<d> dList;
        ...many getters and setters and some logic functions...
    }

    public abstract class ScheduleObserver{
        public abstract void update();
    }

    public interface ILibrary {
        List<PD> getPDs();
        void setPDs(List<PD> newPDs);
        int getCurrentIndex();
        void addPD(PD pD);
        PD getPD(int index);
    }
```

Many thanks.

THANKS - ANSWERED SUCCESSFULLY - it was the IEnumerable that was the source of my woes.  To solve it, dg no longer extends IEnumerable and all foreach (dg...) loops have been converted back into for(int i = 0...) loops.

THANKS VERY, VERY MUCH! JAMES got why its empty, Parv got why had square brackets.  Would mark both as answer but can only mark one.

Comment: `dg`=`[serializable]`?

Comment: does dg have a constructor that matches the overload in your example and does that overload properly assigns values to corresponding properties?

Comment: @Brad - I get the same result with or without [Serializable] tag on dg

Comment: @Dmitri - yes, has constructor, and can step through in debug to see dg object is correct (not same code as above but can be done)

Comment: You haven't posted the implementation of `ScheduleObserver` but from what I can see you don't have any *public* setters/getters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the [source](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/untmp/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/fx/src/xsp/System/Extensions/Script/Serialization/JavaScriptSerializer@cs/1305376/JavaScriptSerializer@cs) the problem would appear to be a combination of a couple of things.

As @Parv has already pointed out the reason you get the `[]` is because your class implements `IEnumerable` so the serializer attempts to *iterate* the object and then serialize each item independently. Your current design is not going to work as it isn't designed to serialize public properties for types that implement `IEnumerable`.

The other issue, like I mentioned in a comment, is the your class doesn't appear to have any public properties, what you have at the moment are public *variables*. In order for the serializer to work you need property setter/getters i.e.

```
public class dg
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem might be that because the `dg` class inherits `IEnumerable`, the `JavaScriptSerializer` is treating it as an `Array` and hence the square brackets.

Try doing

```
var result = serializer.Serialize(
    new dg(1999, "hithere").Select(d => new{ id = d.id, title = d.title }));
```

Comment: @James IEnumerable is an Implemented Interface for Type dg

Comment: very cool...And I was only using ienumerable for foreach loops